# Rasterio.merge removing images

Tags: python, geospatial, raster, rasterio, landsat

I am experimenting with merging landsat 8 bands. My dataset has several B3 bands close together

```
import rasterio 
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.merge import merge
from rasterio.warp import reproject

import os 
from matplotlib import pyplot


files_to_merge = []
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".TIF") and ("GM" not in file):
        files_to_merge.append(rasterio.open(file))

test, out_trans = merge(files_to_merge)
show(test)
```

When I above the above code I get:

[merged image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9l70.png)

The files to merge list has the following objects:

```
 <open DatasetReader name='LE07_L1TP_017015_20210503_20210529_02_T1_B3.TIF' mode='r'>,
 <open DatasetReader name='LC08_L1TP_016015_20210504_20210517_02_T1_B3.TIF' mode='r'>,
 <open DatasetReader name='LE07_L1TP_017016_20210503_20210529_02_T1_B3.TIF' mode='r'>,
 <open DatasetReader name='LC08_L1TP_016014_20210504_20210517_02_T1_B3.TIF' mode='r'>,
 <open DatasetReader name='LE07_L1TP_017014_20210503_20210529_02_T1_B3.TIF' mode='r'>,
```

I am a bit confused why the other raster images arent showing up in the merged image. When I remove the first band I can rerun the merge command:

```
test, out_trans = merge([files_to_merge[1],files_to_merge[2], files_to_merge[3], files_to_merge[4]])
show(test,cmap='terrain')
```

[merged image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g8GU.png)

This seems better but also not correct. I am a bit confused what is going on - how can I merge all the images correctly? Any help is apperciated I am new to rasterio.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ever comes across this problem there are a bunch of things wrong

- This is NOT how you merge landsat 7 and 8 images. If you do the tiniest amount of research (which I didn't) you should come across this website: https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-are-band-designations-landsat-satellites?qt-news_science_products=0#qt-news_science_products

Basically Landsat 7 B1 is not the same as Landsat 8 B1, you want to merge Landsat 7 B1 with Landsat 8 B2.

- Landsat 8 sensors are a different scale then Landsat 7. Rescale Landsat 8 to go between 0 and 255